# Problema al abrir un libro excel mediante VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo un Excel con un `UserForm`, desde el cual mediante un `CommandButton` abro otro archivo Excel mediante:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= "XXXX.xlsx"
```

El libro me lo abre bien, pero no puedo editarlo y lo mas grave, no puedo ni cerrarlo.

He probado usar la propiedad de `ReadOnly := False`, en la llamada al `.Open` y sigue igual. He probado a cambiar todas las opciones del centro de confianza de Excel para permitir la edición de todo y bajar la seguridad al mínimo por si fuera ese el problema, pero todo sigue igual.

La cosa es que si paro la macro o cierro el `UserForm` ya puedo editar y hacer lo que quiera con el libro abierto.

He probado incluso a poner un `DoEvents` justo después de abrir el libro por si fuera que el formulario se quedara haciendo sus cosas, pero nada de nada.

¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

pd: Office version 2016 hogar y empresas, legal y activado.

Comment: puedes poner más codigo?

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, por lo visto al abrir el formulario en modo "modal" no deja interactuar con los libros abiertos.

Comment: te recomiendo que te Auto contestes y asi la gente que tenga duda similar sabrá resolverlo y te llevas alguna medalla ;)

Answer (score 2):

Del [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26332/problema-al-abrir-un-libro-excel-mediante-vba#comment43015_26332) del OP

> Ya lo he solucionado, por lo visto al abrir el formulario en modo "modal" no deja interactuar con los libros abiertos.